# Shopify - xml does not show the value of the attribute

Tags: xml, shopify

I have a screen which uses the Shopify API to display pending orders. I added a cart attribute to show the preferred pick up time of their order. This was working fine up until a few weeks ago. Now the xml that I use to display the attribute does not show the value of the attribute on my screen (although it is still being sent through to the admin area).

The code I used to echo the attribute was: < ?php=$xml->{'note-attributes'}->{'note-attribute'}->value ? >

Has there been some changes in the Shopify API over the last couple of weeks? If so what should I now change this code to?

Comment: Can you post the XML you received in the response? That will probably tell you if something changed.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well. I'm not sure if it was intentional or not, but the XML looks like this coming into my webhook:

```
<note-attributes type="array">
<note_attribute>
```

Note that it is note_attribute, with an underscore. I assumed that individual members of that array would be note-attribute as well, but apparently they're not. I have no idea if this is by design or not...

I hope this helps,

Matt

Comment: Just confirmed that Shopify dev is fixing this issue, so they should be consistent.